# Does $F(x)=\int_0^xf(y)dy$ have a weak derivative?

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let $F(x)=\int_0^xf(y)dy$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, here the integral is a Lebesgue integral. If the function $f$ is continuous, then $F$ is continuously differentiable and has as derivative $f$.

Now if $f$ is only locally integrable, does $F$ has a weak derivative in the usual sense, that is, there exists a locally integrable function $G$ such that $\int_0^xF(y)\phi'(y)dy=-\int_0^xG(y)\phi(y)dy$ for all smooth compactly supported function $\phi$? in this case where can I find a proof of this result ?

Comment: Are you using Lebesgue or Riemann integral? Also, how is your function G defined?

Comment: @Keen. $G$ is some function satisfying the equation. $G$ is called the *weak derivative* of $F$.

Comment: @Keen I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: I suspect that (in order to use the "usual" definition) the integral in the second paragraph should be over the domain of $F$ ($\mathbb R$ in this case).

Comment: Writing $L^1$ as the closure of $C^0$ for the $\|.\|_{L^1}$ norm and the Lebesgue integral as the (continuous) extension of the Riemann integral to $L^1$, the statement (integration by parts) becomes true by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and $f$ is the weak derivative.

Assume $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and let $F$ be its primitive function 
$$ F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) \mathbf{1}_{y \le x} dy. $$
Choose any $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. By Fubini's theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(x) \varphi'(x) dx 
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y) \mathbf{1}_{y \le x} dy \right) \varphi'(x) dx \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi'(x) \mathbf{1}_{x \ge y} dx \right) f(y) dy \\
& = - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(y) f(y) dy. 
\end{align*}
If $f$ is merely locally integrable, one needs to extend it by zero outside the support of $\varphi$ (and possibly add a constant to $F$), but the main argument stays the same.

---

I see nothing wrong with approaches of @Pedro or @reuns, but this one seems the most straightforward to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes (and $G=f$). You can find a proof in [Kreuter's text](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/abschlussarbeiten/MA_Marcel_Kreuter.pdf) (Corollary 3.3, p. 23).